# How to subset a dataframe with "5k+2", "5k+2 and 5k+3", and "5k+2 and 5k+3 and 5k+4" patterned-condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe "mydata" with 151 columns (variables) holding 5-system variables at the beginning columns.

```
nx:= no. of independent variables    
ny:= no. of dependent variables    
nz:= no. of variables over which conditioning is performed.
```

nx+ny+nz=5 (nx,ny,nz>0)

The ordering of variables in mydata is regular:
independents....dependents....conditioneds...constant...1stLagsOfIndependents...1stLagsOfDependents...1stLagsOfConditioneds...2ndLagsOfIndependents...2ndLagsOfDependents...2ndLagsOfConditioneds................29ndLagsOfIndependents...29ndLagsOfDependents...29ndLagsOfConditioneds

The mydata's structure is as follows:
5-system-variables constant  1stLagsOfVariables  2ndLagsOfVariables......29thLagsOfVariables
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 ..........1........ V11l V21l....V51l V12l V22l....V52l................V129l V229l....V529l

The index structure is:

```
5.........1......5.........5.............................5   
(1-5)....(6)...(7-11)...(12-16)..................(5*29+2=147 - 151)
```

User specifies no. of independent variables at the beginning:

```
nx <- 1   # or s/he may choose nx <- 2 etc.
```

How to subset mydata in a concise (programmatic) way for lags of specified type? i.e,
For nx=1;
I need to express concisely this one:

```
mydata[,c(7,12,...,147)] # V11l V12l ... V129l   
mydata[,c(5*k+2)] , k=1,...,29
```

For nx=2;
I need to express concisely this one:

```
mydata[,c(7,8,12,13,...,147,148)]  # V11l V21l V12l V22l... V129l V229l  
mydata[,c(5*k+2, 5*k+3)] , k=1,...,29
```

For nx=3;
I need to express concisely this one:

```
mydata[,c(7,8,9,12,13,14,...,147,148,149)] # V11l V21l V31l V12l V22l V32l ... V129l V229l V329l    
mydata[,c(5*k+2, 5*k+3, 5*k+4)] , k=1,...,29
```

nx cannot be 4 since (nx+ny+nz=5 and nx,ny,nz>0).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your examples

Comment: How about `mydata[,(7:151)[rep(c(rep(TRUE, nx), rep(FALSE, 5-nx)), times=29)]]`?

Comment: @WeihuangWong I tried it with `nx=1` and it gave the error: `mydata[,(7:151)[rep(c(rep(TRUE, 1), rep(FALSE, 5-1)), times=29)]]` 
Error in `[.default`(mydata, , (7:151)[rep(c(rep(TRUE, 1), rep(FALSE,  : 
  subscript out of bounds; Also gave error for the cases `nx=2` and `nx=3`

Comment: `(7:151)[rep(c(rep(TRUE, 1), rep(FALSE, 5-1)), times=29)]` returns `7, 12, ..., 147`, which is the same as the desired output above.  What is `ncol(mydata)`?

Comment: There are 151 columns in mydata; First 5 are system variables; then a constant, then 1stLags, 2ndLags,...,29thLags of these system variables.

Comment: @WeihuangWong, Thanks a lottttt. You can add it as an answer. I applied. I made a mistake during application previously. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mydata[,(7:151)[rep(c(rep(TRUE, nx), rep(FALSE, 5-nx)), times=29)]]`.